# Influxdb2 How to Use windowPeriod in Arithmetic

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I am trying to calculate my energy cost with datapoints published to my influxdb. I need to utilize `windowPeriod` in order to go back far enough in time. I am currently taking a sum of my energy usage and trying to do arithmetic on it, which if I use hard coded times is no problem. But that doesn't scale at all.

```
from(bucket: "energydata")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["device_name"] == "Home-14")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["detailed"] == "False")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> sum(column: "_value")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r._value * 0.13806 / (float(v: int(v: v.windowPeriod)) / 1000000000.0 * 60.0 ) }))
```

I believe it is when trying to convert the `windowPeriod` into something useful that it breaks. As I change my period of review my results are all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out, in case anyone wants to know:

```
from(bucket: "energydata")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["device_name"] == "Home")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["detailed"] == "False")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> sum(column: "_value")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r._value * (float(v: int(v: v.windowPeriod)) / (16000000000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 60.0) ) * 0.13806 }))
```

Where `0.13806` is your cost per kWh. This converts `windowPeriod` into hours, and gets you kilowatt hours which you can use to make calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The `v.windowPeriod` is a dynamic variable being set by the UI to make graphs looks better, I don't think it's the right thing to use for calculating costs.

And are you sure that you want to take the `mean` average of your values in windowed intervals before calculating the `sum`? I'm not sure what your actual data looks like, but this feels like it might be the wrong approach.

Comment: There isn't really a great option. But it gets me really close. I was able to figure it out, meaning out the usage across a time period, then converting it to an hourly rate allowed me to get very close to real cost.